# String Index out of range issue while making a function that counts vowels

Tags: python

I am trying to make a function that counts all the vowels using recursion and I keep getting string index out of range.

```
def vowels(s):
    vowel = "AEIOUaeiou"
    if s == " ":
        return 0
    if s[0] in vowel:
        return 1 + vowels(s[1:])
    else:
        return vowels(s[1:])

print(vowels("Hello Planet Me"))
```

I am expecting a number of vowels in a string and I just get error on lines 8 and 10 repeating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line

```
if s == " ":
```

to

```
if s == "":
```

or

```
if len(s) == 0:
```

or, the best way is to use the boolean value of `str` type in python which returns a `False` if the `str` is empty.

```
if not s:
```

For the base case, an empty string is passed to the function and not a `space` character.

Answer (score 1):

if you just change your initial `if` condition to

```
if not s:
    return 0
```

you will be fine. that way you just return `0` if the string is empty an you do not get to the line containing `s[1:]` (which will raise the error you encountered).

a simple non-recursive way would be:

```
VOWELS = set("AEIOUaeiou")

def vowels(s):
    return sum(char in VOWELS for char in s)
```

(as `True` is just an alias for `1` and `False` is an alias for `0` you can just `sum` the booleans).